# Is it possible to make a "pyc only" "distribution"?

Tags: python

Say I have a python code base organized like so:

```
./mod/:
    ./__init__.py
    ./main/main.py
    ./main/__init__.py
    ./mytest/__init__.py
```

The file

```
mod/main/__init__.py
```

is empty. And

```
$ cat mod/main/main.py 
    import sys
    import mytest
    def main(argv):
        mytest.test()
        return
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

And

```
$ cat mod/mytest/__init__.py 
def test():
    print('test worked!')
```

As expected, this works (from within the directory "mod"):

```
$ python3 -m main.main
test worked!
```

Now, I want to remove all the .py files, and still be able to run the command that I have above - or something very similar. "Very similar" is defined by not having to change my code structure at all - or, if that cannot be done, as little as possible.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: If you're hoping to prevent people from reading your code this way, forget it. `.pyc` files aren't obfuscated and almost can't be. Python even comes with a Python disassembler built in, so people who can run your code don't even need to download any additional tools to start taking it apart.

Comment: The only reason to do this is to addressing handling questions coming from from edited scripts being run. People edit, forget, run, ask. This way I can create the pyc files, and if there is a question on what I created - I can handle it - else people can figure out that they have edited the code and should address their question themselves.

Comment: Wouldn't you also be limiting your user base to people using the same architecture you compiled it on in the first place?

Answer (score 5):

the

```
compileall
```

utility with the "-b" option did the thing for me.